# why is lithium oxide so different from water

Tags: periodic-trends

Take water and replace hydrogens with the next element down in the periodic table, and you get a white solid, nothing like water.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_oxide
Lithium itself is very different from hydrogen, but it's isoelectronic and only has a few more nucleons. You'd think if there was any sense to this periodic table thing they'd be similar...

Comment: Take water and drop below 0C. You get a often white solid.

Comment: Periodic table only accounts for chemical and some very basic physical properties, it, by no means, takes into consideration the phase in which a compound is which is formed when an element combines with another.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hydrogen is not isoelectronic to lithium. According to wikipedia, for example, $\ce{CO, CN−, N2, C2^2-, and NO+}$ are isoelectronic because they have the same electronic structure. Typically, elements in the same group are not described as isoelectronic (like the noble gases).

Moreover, hydrogen is less of a typical group 1 element than, for example, fluorine is a typical group 17 element. Looking at the electron configuration, hydrogen has a single electron in the outer shell (like group 1 metals), has its out shell half-filled (like carbon), and is one electron away from noble gas configuration (like group 17 elements).

You don't even have to discuss compounds and ions formed to see that hydrogen behaves very differently from lithium. It is sufficient to compare the elements. Hydrogen is a diatomic gas (like many non-metals) while lithium is a ductile metal.

Comment: I see. It's far more complicated than being in the same column.